# $f$ a differentiable fucntion in $[a,b]$ with $f´(a) < C < f´(b)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f$ a differentiable fucntion in $[a,b]$, suppose the existence of a point $C$ with $f´(a) < C < f´(b)$ how can i deduce that given the function $g(x) = f(x) - C(x-a)$ then exist a pint $x_0$ with $a<x_0<b$ such that $f´(x_0) = C$.

Some help please i stuck i tried to use mean value theorem but i can prove the existence of this $x_0$ satisfying that $f´(x_0) = C$.

Comment: This is also known as [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29).

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen, beat me to it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: $g$ is a differentiable function. $g'(a) < 0$, $g'(b) > 0$. $g$ must have a minimum on $[a, b]$ at a point in $(a, b)$ (why?). What value does $g'$ take at this point?

Comment: $g´(a) = f´(a)-C$ and $g´(b) = f´(b) -C$ ?

Comment: @Knight $g'(x) = f'(x) - C$. Your calculations are incorrect.

Comment: @G.T.R I don't assume $g'$ to be continuous. On the other hand, $g$ is continuous and differentiable, since $f$ is.